# Is there any difference between `element` and `iElement` in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and jQuery, AngularJS official tutorial using `iElement` to inject, but some other tutorial using `element`, is there any different? the following `btn1` and `btn2` also work, `element` and `iElement` also will wrap by jQuery.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('btn1', function () {
    return function (scope, element) {
        element.click(function () {
            $(this).css('background', '#666');
        });
    };
});

app.directive('btn2', function () {
    return function (scope, iElement) {
        iElement.click(function () {
            $(this).css('background', '#666');
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no difference, both are just two variable names. You can use any name instead of element/iElement like el/eleme etc, the only factor that matters in this is the values passed to the callback in this case it is the `link` callback function which passes the scope, element, attributes and controllers.

When it matters is when you use it an environment where argument injection is used like in the  controller function or in the directive function where the parameter names are used for injecting the parameters

Comment: Oh, so `link` callback is not using the parameter name to inject ? it just call using the order of parameter ?

Comment: @WingLeong yes... since it is a callback function it uses predefined parameters

Comment: Ha, thank you, before now, I think Angular inject every function XD